# How to put two git repository into one project on sourcesup

Tags: git, merge, project, addition

Hi every body I'm student in master degres I work at INRAE. 
I have a problem when trying to clone different repositories into one :
I have a git project "p1"
git project "P2"
and I want to create a project "Project" on sourcesup and then add the two projects.
at the end I want to have a tree like this
-Project
--------P1
--------P2

I tried a lot of commands but nothings works or give me what I'm searching for
I hope I will finf a solution with your help
Thank you

Comment: Git does not support "cloning different repositories into one" at least by the meaning of "git clone". The closest thing you can find in git is [submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).

Comment: tnx for answering
I m working on sourcesup and not git

Answer (score 0):

GIT has a feature called submodules where you can have multiple git repositories inside a main repository. You can then clone the small main project independently from the sub projects. Mediawiki uses this approach to separate skins from the main project

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

The submodule will be empty when you clone the main project, except for the .git/config which allows you to update the submodule after the main repository

```
git submodule update --init
```

You can clone the submodules together with the main project with the recurse-submodules flag

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/chaconinc/MainProject
```

If you don't want to have independent git repositories but merge the two project, you can use git merge where you need the flag --allow-unrelated-histories to allow them to have independent histories.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Comment: tnx for your commentyes I already tried this but when I clone the project into eclipse for example I have an empty module